# Designing a flexible Key class in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, gwt

I am trying to design a generic Key class in java to represent primary pojo keys.

The values can be of various types i.e. BigInteger, String, Uuid's . I am looking for best option to implement such a class. My current implementation looks something like this.

Can anyone help me with a more accurate implementation or identify issues with the current implementation? I am yet to implement a equals method. Any pointers are welcome.

This class needs to be GWT compatible.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@GwtCompatible
public class Key<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

public enum KeyType {
    BigInt, Uuid, String ;

}

private final T keyValue  ;
private final KeyType keyType  ;

Key() {
    keyValue = null;
    keyType = null;
}

public Key(T value){
    this.keyValue =  value ;
    this.keyType = determineKeyType(value);
}

/**
 * @return
 */
private KeyType determineKeyType(Object value) {

    if ( isValueUuid(value))
        return KeyType.Uuid ;

    else if (value instanceof BigInteger)
        return KeyType.BigInt ;

    else 
        return KeyType.String; 
}

/**
 * @param value
 * @return
 */
private boolean isValueUuid(Object value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public Key(T val, KeyType tp){
    this.keyValue = val ;
    this.keyType = tp;
}

public KeyType getKeyType(){
    return keyType ;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return super.equals(obj);
}

public T getKeyValue(){
    return this.keyValue ;
}
}
```

Comment: Is there an existing  GWT compatible implementation available that does something more or less like this? What are the best practices applicable in this case ?

Comment: Note - Some methods are yet to be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me me that you would benefit from a [Factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) here.

You would have an interface `Key`, an `AbstractKey`, and as many implementations of this `AbstractKey` as you want (in your example case, it should be 3). The KeyFactory would be in charge of creating the key.

Practically, it would give:

```
public interface Key<T> extends Serializable {
    T getKeyValue();
}

public abstract class AbstractKey<T> implements Key<T> {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj instanceof AbstractKey) {
            return getKeyValue().equals(((AbstractKey) obj).getKeyValue());
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class StringKey extends AbstractKey<String> {

    private String keyValue;

    StringKey() {
        super();
    }

    protected StringKey(String val) {
        super(val);
        this.keyValue = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String getKeyValue() {
        return keyValue;
    }
}

public class BigIntKey extends AbstractKey<BigInteger> {

    private BigInteger keyValue;

    BigIntKey() {
        super();
    }

    protected BigIntKey(BigInteger val) {
        super(val);
        this.keyValue = val;
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger getKeyValue() {
        return keyValue;
    }
}

...

public class KeyFactory {
    public static Key<String> getKey(String obj) {
        return new StringKey(obj);
    }

    public static Key<BigInteger> getKey(BigInteger obj) {
        return new BigIntKey(obj);
    }
}
```

One advantage of this solution, even if it's more verbose than the one you already have, is that you can restrict the types of your `Key`s to what you actually need. In addition, with constructors that have limited visibility (just enough to make GWT compile properly), you can enforce the code to use the `KeyFactory`.

Comment: Any idea what will it look like if we want to avoid the factory and use guice injection ? Can we attain the same result by using a guice provider / binding ?

Comment: There is one issue here from my need perspective. What happens when I receive a Key reference and I don't know the type ? i.e. I won't be able to determine the type of the Key inside. how do you propose we overcome that ?

Comment: You can have another method in the `Key` interface `getType()` and the implementation classes would implement it in that way: `Class<?> getType() { return keyValue.getClass();}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the rest but your `equals` delegates to the `equals` of `Object` which is identity based. Is this what you want? It seems not since you want to check for keys that could be of various types.
Also if you override `equals` then you **must** override `hashCode`